# Convert audio Uri to byte array

Tags: android

I need to convert an audio Uri to a byte array in order to store it in a SQLite BLOB. I already managed to do that with images, by converting them into bitmaps first, but I have no idea on how to do this for audios as well.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

> do that with images, by converting them into bitmaps first,

Well that is a bad approach as that bitmap takes an awfull lot of memory. And after that you compress it to a baos (ByteArrayOutputStream) i think. And then convert to byte array. So the complete file is in the baos and in the array. All spilled memory.

Instead you should directly declare a byte array with the size of the file and then load the bytes of the file in that array. Thats all.

Once you have done that for images your code is ready for all files. No difference. Just loading the bytes of a file in a byte array.